# Problem with Java instalation

Tags: java

I am trying to install Cytoscape on my Ubuntu machine and I get this error:

> No suitable Java Virtual Machine could be found on your system.
> The version of the JVM must be at least 11.0 and at most 12.
> Please define INSTALL4J_JAVA_HOME to point to a suitable JVM.

Here is the output of `java -version`

> openjdk version "9-internal"
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src)
> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-internal+0-2016-04-14-195246.buildd.src, mixed mode)

I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: you have openjdk 9 installed.. for Cytoscape you need to have at least openjdk 11 which you can install with sudo apt install opendjk-11-jdk-headless

Comment: Seems my version of Ubuntu is too old, 16.04. Can it be installed by downloading from Java website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I install Sun/Oracle's proprietary Java JDK 6/7/8 or JRE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56104/how-can-i-install-sun-oracles-proprietary-java-jdk-6-7-8-or-jre) **Note:** Here Java version doesn't really matter. From Oracle's site, you'll get an archive and the installation procedure would be same as in the answers on that question. Also, note that `javaws` is no longer available. You can skip commands including `javaws`.

Comment: https://tecadmin.net/install-oracle-java-11-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial/

Comment: Just that Oracle has changed its license. I can't download anything.